# Install java in a linux server without admin rights

Tags: bash, software-installation, java, oracle, paths

I am using a cloud computing server were I don't have admin rights, for biology research which has java's
version:

```
 user@server:~$ java -version     

 java version "1.4.2"
 gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

 Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

For some programs, I need java's version 1.8. I have tried to install java in a directory and then add it to my PATH via the .bashrc file.

However, if I do

```
user@server:~$ java -version
```

I still have "1.4.2" version. How could I fix it in order to use Java 1.8?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

Instalation process:

I went to https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml and downloaded the file.

Then, inside my server I have unpacked with:

```
tar -xvf jre-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

And then I have add the following line to my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/my_user/programs/java/jre1.8.0_101
```

Comment: Please describe (show exact steps) how you installed Java 8 and how you added the location to PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the binary executables which you have to add to `$PATH` in your setup is

```
/home/my_user/programs/java/jre1.8.0_101/bin
```

(you forgot the `/bin`).

Additionally, you want your added location to have the highest priority (it must override the system's default location of `java`), so you need to swap the order of the directory and the old `$PATH` content.

Simply edit the line you added to your `.bashrc` file to:

```
export PATH=/home/my_user/programs/java/jre1.8.0_101/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to reload the `.bashrc` file by either closing and reopening the terminal or by running `source .bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey check button on its left to mark your question as solved. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is not solving my problem, if do java -version I get java 1.4.2

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you need to put the new location to the beginning of the `$PATH` variable so that it has a higher priority than the system's default. I edited my answer, it should work now.